# MAX - 1 php ?? Does it exist?

Tags: php, max

I tried to get the 2nd highest value from an array and I simply want to know if it is possible to do something like  MAX -1  OR  I absolutely  need to sort by table and  the 2nd highest value

```
private function max_key($array) {
    foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
    if ($val == max($array))  return $key;
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 $a = Array ( 1, 2, 40 , 100);
 echo max($a) - 1; // definitely not 40
```

So yes, you'd need to `rsort()` ([built-in PHP function, sorts the array with highest values first](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rsort.php)), and then take the 2nd value from the list.

Note that e.g. `array( 1 , 10 , 5 , 10 )` has second value == first value; if you want the second-largest unique value, run it through `array_unique()` first.

Comment: Should be rather `$a[count($a)-2]` after `sort()`. Otherwise `rsort()` should be used.

Answer (score 6):

Seems that there is no such standart function(It's too specific).
You may sort and get second value, but it's `O(n log n)` complexity.

There is `O(n) solution`

```
function second_key($array){
    $max=null;
    $second = null;
    foreach($array as $k => $v){
        if(!isset($max) || $v > $array[$max]){
            $second = $max;
            $max = $k;
        }
        elseif(!isset($second) || $v > $array[$second]){
             $second = $k;
        }
    }
    return $second;
}
```

Comment: +1 the way to go. I would just suggest to improve code formatting a little bit, e.g. adding spaces before & after operators like `>`, `=`, and the `=>` in foreach, for better readability.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use a qsort algorithm ( more readable code, less debugging ). If your array/table is very huge ( and so also qsort can create reasonable performance problem to your code ), you can probably perform a linear search storing in 2 vars the "max" and "max-1" elements: not too much expensive to do, but you need to understand if that work can give you real advantage.

Another aproach could be try to keep sorted your array directly at its source ( SQL / DB table ).

Answer (score 0):

```
sort( $array, SORT_NUMERIC );
echo $array[ count( $array ) - 2 ];
```

Answer (score 0):

`max($array) - 1` isn't going to work. I would do something like:

```
$array = arsort($array);
return isset( $array[1] ) ? $array[1] : FALSE;
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you will find a MAX - 1 function.  Probably need to do a type of sort, then take the second position in the sorted array.

Comment: Bubble sort? BUBBLE SORT? Why on Earth are you recommending one of the least efficient algorithms, and also reinventing the wheel to top it off? See also: The Fine Manual - http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php